# Why can’t I post an answer to a question titled: “ASUS Armoury Crate installation fails with error 102”

Tags: discussion, windows-10

Of the questions I have only one: why, if I found a possible solution and registered only to write an answer, I can't do it because I don't have a reputation? It turns out to be absurd.

**But I have an answer to a topic with the same name:**
[ASUS Armoury Crate installation fails with error 102](https://superuser.com/q/1711874/167207)

I ran into the same problem, and it helped me: disable all tweaks disabling metrics, monitoring and other data collection in the Win 10 Tweaker I use. If you use any similar program, for example, the same O&O ShutUp10, or you installed a custom build of Windows 10 with tweaks sewn in or manually did tweaks (related to Privacy) through the registry editor, group policies or services - they need to be rolled back. It helped me to go through the installation to the end.

Comment: Questions about aspects of the site (like rep requirements) belong on [meta]. // This is a [protected question](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Comment: There are very low bars to answering and commenting in order to the simplest of spam. The bars are very low.

Answer (score 5):

The question you want to answer is [protected](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). This is a special mode that can be automatically or manually enabled for questions that are receiving lots of low-quality or non-answers. You cannot see them, but there are two deleted “me too” non-answers to this question.

The minimum required rep to answer protected questions (10 points IIRC) is inconsequential for all existing users. All it takes is one or two upvotes. Furthermore, if you’re already an established user on a different Stack Exchange site, you get a 100 point bonus when joining a Stack Exchange site.

You can still answer non-protected questions right from the start and are encouraged to do so!

Comment: @FranciskRae - The question was protected due to multiple user’s submitting “me too” answers. The answer you describe is more a comment than an actual answer. The answer you want to submit does not answer the author’s question.